# How do I create a "two pass" package in SSIS to get extra details?

Tags: ssis, iteration

I need to create an SSIS package that will do the following:

1. Connect to Service A and download recent activity records. These records contain an User Id and an activity code.
2. Iterate through the results of the result set from Service A and connect to Service B retrieve additional details for each User Id (name, department, etc.).
3. Put all of the results from this "two pass" scenario into a DataTable on our SQL Server.

I'm able to do parts 1 and 3 without issue, but I'm having difficulties in how to implement part 2.

Do I put the results from part 1 into the destination table and then iterate through the results in a second Data Flow Task? Or is there a way to "append" the results from steps 1 and 2 into a single table/file/etc. and push the results into the destination table all at once?

I'm seeing all the controls available in BIDS, but can't seem to make them fit.

Comment: Is step 1 just retrieving data from a database or something else?

Comment: Step 1 comes from a service that lists our recent transactions. I give it a timestamp in which to retrieve all new activity. Step 2 is coming from a seperate service that stores all the user data.

Comment: Sorry, as a followup, Step 1 is a web service, but I'm using an XSLT to get a nice datatable style format from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dataflow tab:

1. Use 1 of the dataflow sources (XML source)
2. Use the Lookup Transformation
3. SQL Destination

Comment: Do I target the Lookup Transformation to my destination database or to an intermediate column before pushing it through to the end.?

Comment: Yes, Datasource(1) connects to Lookup Transformation(2) connects to SQL Destination(3)

The Lookup component adds any new columns you need before sending it to the SQL Destination.

Comment: I think this is going to do the trick. I was digging into this and noticed that you can specify new columns as opposed to existing ones in the output. I'll give this a whirl and update accordingly.

Comment: This did it! I changed things slightly to use a Script Transformation since I was calling a web service, but the process worked out the same. Thanks!